# How to read excel file programmatically (.xlsx) in chunks i.e in group of 5000 rows, in an android application?

Tags: java, android, dalvik

How can I read large xlsx files

Error comes since I am loading whole excel file in memory.Is there anyway so that I can read excel file in chunks so that memory consumption will reduce?
I am using "Aspose Cells for Android" library for reading excel files. Please help.

error is

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: [memory exhausted]
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: What exactly *is* the requirement? Serving them? Processing them *as* Excel files?

Comment: Have a look at [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html). Its a pure Java Excel API and supports streaming. Didn't try it on Android.

Comment: @EJP - I want to read the rows and use them for comparison. But I cant read the excel files (application works perfectly as required with smaller size excel files).

Answer (score 1):

The .xlsx file actually is xml based zipped file, that's why they take small disk space than legacy .xls format. You can change the file extension to .zip to check internal.

So what the API does is un-zip the file first, then read it.
Memory exhausted may happened during un-zipping.

If the size is 10Mb, the actually un-zipped size in memory may be over 1Gb, you can try to configure  your handset by adding more visual memory in android.

Or just cutting down the big file to pieces of small files in PC in one folder, then treat the folder with your app.

Comment: @EJP - I am newbie to Java development can you please guide how to proceed with cutting the files in small files.. Thanks.

Comment: use this https://github.com/kiranbjm/xlsxparser